# Run doesn't work in Eclipse with Cygwin toolchain

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, cygwin

I was trying to configure my Eclipse to use Cygwin toolchain.
I wrote a simple C++ program to check I have setup things correctly.

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ofstream fout("output.txt");
    fout << "Hi" << endl;
    fout.close();

    return 0;
}
```

The build button compiles the program and generates the executable and I can run it.

However when I click on the run button in Eclipse it doesn't run the program.
I am rather confused since the debug button runs the program correctly (so the issue should not be not finding cygwin1.dll).

The run button works if I set the toolchain to MinGW.

I am using Eclipse Kepler Service Release 1 and my Cygwin is up to date.

I search a bit but I couldn't find an answer to how to fix this.
Any suggestion about what might be the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solved the problem for me:

1. Add Cygwin to `PATH` in the environment, e.g. `C:\Cygwin\bin\`
2. Add a path mapping for Cygwin drives in `Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Debug -> Source Lookup Path`, e.g. map `\cygdrive\c` to `C:\`.

Comment: @AlG, yes, I know. I still need to wait another 6 hours.